# How to prove that the limit is zero?

Tags: limits

> Given $m\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(n^m\exp (-n))=0$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint: $n^m = \exp(m\cdot\ln n)$
So: $n^m\cdot \exp(-n) = \exp(-n + m\cdot\ln n)$
I assume you can go on from here.

Comment: May I suggest `\cdot` to write nice multiplication dots? Also I think `\exp` will make it into a nice operator that is not in italic, namely $\exp(x)$.

Comment: @String Sure, thanks. I am not fluent in MathJax.